# gatsby-remark-images-medium-zoom not working

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am creating a blog with Gatsbyjs.
The content is taken from contentful and the content type is markdown.
graphql is:

```
contentfulBlogPost(id: { eq: $id }) {
  content {
    childMdx {
      body
    }
  }
}
```

The acquired body is passed to the following components.

```
const Markdown = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <MDXProvider>
      <MDXRenderer>{children}</MDXRenderer>
    </MDXProvider>
  </div>
)
```

```
<Markdown>{data.contentfulBlogPost.content.childMdx.body}</Markdown>
```

gatsby-config is:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          `gatsby-remark-images`,
          `gatsby-remark-images-medium-zoom`
        ],
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 500,
              linkImagesToOriginal: false,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images-medium-zoom`,
            options: {}
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

Medium-zoom does not work with this configuration.

Thank you in advance.